# Validation of a Date input

Tags: javascript

The user inputs their date of birth and they must be between 15 and 80 years old.

The Javascript:
I currently have **dob = Date Of Birth**

```
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var minDate = new Date('04/30/1937');
var maxDate = new Date('04/30/2004');

if (dob < minDate) {
    result = false;
    errMsg = errMsg + "You are too old to be applying for this position/n"
} else if(dob > maxDate) {
    result = false;
    errMsg = errMsg + "You are too young to be applying for this position/n"             
}
```

The **HTML**:

```
<legend>Personal Details</legend>
<p><label for="dob">Date of Birth</label></p>
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" required="required"/>
```

**Edit. I didn't state the issue I was having, the issue was that even though I would enter a dob that was outside the min-max range, I wouldn't receive either of the error messages. Setting dob as a `new Date` fixed the issue

Comment: What's your question? What doesn't work? What do you expect to see versus what do you see?

Comment: Hey you have to change your dob variable to the format of minDate or maxDate by taking months and all or by formatting on input element. Then only try to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have in your code is good. but you need to pass your `dob` value in `new Date(dob)`

```js
var minDate = new Date('04/30/1937');
var maxDate =  new Date('04/30/2004');
var dob = new Date('09/14/1993'); //new date(dob). I used a hardcoded date

if (dob < minDate) {
  result = false;
  console.log("You are too old to be applying for this position")
} else if(dob > maxDate ) {
  result = false;
  console.log("You are too young to be applying for this position")
} else {
  result = true;
  console.log("success")
}
```